# Apostrophes come out garbled when read from a .txt file

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have a problem when reading lines from .txt file.  My file contains sentences with words such as

> hadn’t , can’t, didn’t

and so on, and the problem is that when i use `read()` method insted of

> ’

I have something like that:

> â€™

So my read word is `hadnâ€™t` instead of `hadn’t`

My input:

```text
Love at First Sight

One <adjective> afternoon, I was walking by the <place> when
accidentally I bumped into a <adjective> boy.
At first I blushed and apologized for bumping into him, but when he flashed his
<adjective> smile I just couldn’t help falling in love. His
<adjective> voice telling me that it was ok sounded like music to myears.
I could have stayed there staring at him for <period_of_time>.
He had <adjective> <color> eyes and <adjective>
<color> hair. I thought he was perfect for me. Before I noticed,
<number> <period_of_time> had passed by after I apologized,
and I hadn’t said anything else since!
That’s when I noticed thathe was looking at me
<adverb>. I didn’t know what tosay, so I just <past_verb>.
I noticed him giving me astrange look when he started walking to his
<noun>.I looked back at him <number> more time(s), but hewas already out of sight.
It wasn’t love after all
```

Expected output: same as input file

My code:

```
f = open('loveatfirstsight.txt','r')
for i in f.readlines():
    print(i)
```

My operating system: Windows 10

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include a minimal working version of your code together with a sample .txt file.

Comment: @JohnnyJohnBoy: are you kidding me? Not even the first edit was actually necessary, the very first version had enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @user https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it's clear that there needs to be an expected outcome in the question.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? There are differences between Python 2 and 3 regarding encoding, and Python 3.6 changed the default encodings on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file is encoded in UTF-8, but you are reading it as if it were (I assume) windows-1252 (or some other Windows-specific encoding). Since the apostrophe character appearing in this file is not the typical ASCII ‘typewriter apostrophe’ (`'` U+0027 APOSTROPHE), but a ‘typographer’s apostrophe’ (`’` U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) which lies outside the Basic Latin (‘ASCII’) block, the mismatched encoding makes the character come out mangled.

```
>>> 'hadn’t'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')
'hadnâ€™t'
```

To correct this problem, you should specify the correct encoding via the `encoding` parameter to the `open` function.

```
f = open('loveatfirstsight.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
for i in f.readlines():
    print(i)
```

As `help(open)` explains,

> In text mode, if `encoding` is not specified the encoding used is platform
> dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the
> current locale encoding. (For reading and writing raw bytes use binary
> mode and leave `encoding` unspecified.)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an encoding issue. The text file is stored in UTF-8 with curly quotes in it. You're either reading it with the wrong encoding (perhaps Latin-1) or you're outputting it in UTF-8 to somewhere (perhaps a Windows console?) that's not expecting the UTF-8 encoding.

If the question is revised to include more details about how exactly the data is stored, read and processed, including things like what system you're on and what version of Python you're using, you'll be able to get better answers.